# How to modify only one Key-Value pair in an NSMutableDictionnary

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

If I have an NSMutableDictionnary with 4 Key Value pairs (stored in a .plist), When I load the dictionary from the .plist how can I modify only one of the Key Value Pairs without erasing the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change a single value for the given key like so:

```
[dict setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
```

Answer (score 1):

`[dictionary setObject:value forKey:key]` will assign the value for the specified key; `[dictionary removeObjectForKey:key]` will remove the key-value pair completely.